# How to create populated MySQL Docker Image on build time

Tags: mysql, database, docker

I would like to create a MySQL Docker image with data already populated.

I want to create 3 layers like this:

```
        |---------------------|---------------------|
Layer 3 | Customer 1 Database | Customer 2 Database |
        |---------------------|---------------------|
Layer 2 |   Database image with tables but no data  |
        |-------------------------------------------|
Layer 1 |                mysql:5.6.26               |
        |-------------------------------------------|
```

My question is now how to create a correct Dockerfile for layer 2 and 3?
Where my empty_with_tables.sql file is loaded into layer 2 and customer1.sql and customer2.sql is loaded into two images in layer 3. I read something about putting SQL files into '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d'. But this would result in the data being when the image is started for the first time. This not what I want. I want the data to be ready in the image (for example to be quickly available in testing).

I could start the mysql image, load the data from commandline and do a 'commit' but this is not reproducible, requiring doing that again when data in the SQL files are changed.

How can this be done?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So my solution to this problem was just NOT to layer everything but create a base image and use --volumes-from to inject the database files from a data-only container.

Comment: Could you give more info, please ? I'd like to do it as well.

Comment: @Morten Green please take time and share your work, we are here to help each other.

Answer (score 25):

I ran into the same problem this week. I've found a working solution without the need for `--volumes-from`

The problem that's already stated is that `/var/lib/mysql` is a volume, and since Docker is not going to support `UNVOLUME` in it's Dockerfile in the near future, you can't use this location for your database storage if you want to start off with an empty database by default. (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18287). That's why I overwrite `etc/mysqld.my.cnf`, giving mysql a new datadir.

Together with pwes' his answer, you can create a Dockerile like this:

```
FROM mysql:5.6

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE db
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD pass
COPY db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
RUN /entrypoint.sh mysqld & sleep 30 && killall mysqld
RUN rm /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql
```

The only change there is in `my.cnf` is the location of the datadir:

```
.... 
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql2 <-- can be anything except /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
....
```

Comment: Following all together (including below modification), and getting an error when I try to start a container built like this, "[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table storage engine for 'user' doesn't have this option"  (MySQL 5.7 on MacOS, Docker 2.1.0.5)

Answer (score 8):

This cannot be done cleanly the exact way you want it to, at least when basing on official `mysql` image, because you need to communicate with the server to import the data and the server is not run and initialized (from mysql's [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.6/docker-entrypoint.sh)) until the container is run, which is only when the image is already built.

The not-so-clean way is to run the process in the container, using the `/entrypoint.sh` script from mysql image, but you must take care of all the settings required by the entrypoint (like `$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`) as well as a clean way to stop the daemon just after importing the data. Something like:

```
FROM mysql:5.6

ADD data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00-import-data.sql
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD somepassword
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE db1
RUN /entrypoint.sh mysqld & sleep 30 && killall mysqld
```

is a hackish way that results in pre-initialized DB, but... it doesn't work. The reason is that `/var/lib/mysql` is declared as a volume in mysql's Dockerfile, and any changes to this directory during build process are lost after the build step is done. This can be observed in the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.6

RUN touch /var/lib/mysql/some-file && ls /var/lib/mysql
RUN touch /var/lib/mysql/some-file2 && ls /var/lib/mysql
```

So I suggest going with `docker commit` way you described. The end result is the same as the one you want to achieve, with an exception of Layer 2 maybe.

**UPDATE**: As OP commented below, the commit doesn't contain volumes either. So, the only way seems to be to either edit MySQL Dockerfile and remove `VOLUME` to keep data inside the container, or to manage the volumes separately from containers.

Comment: Hello! I am sorry for the late answer!
Isn't there a problem with the commit method? in the official Dockerfile a volume is defined ('VOLUME /var/lib/mysql') and this is just where the databases are located. Therefore a commit will not include those files in a new image (I did a check with 'docker diff <containerid>'). And I cannot 'un-volume' mounts can I?

Comment: You're right; this is a general problem with volumes being opaque to any commit (hence it doesn't work during build). See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6999. People generally clone the original repo and move VOLUME after their custom modifications, or remove it all together -- see https://github.com/stuartpb/rethinkdb-dockerfiles/issues/14

Answer (score 6):

MegaWubs's answer is great, except for this "sleep 30" that forces you to guess initdb's execution time.
To avoid this, I put a small shell script to be executed after every others in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d :

```
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
  |- 01_my_data1.sql
  |- 02_my_data2.sql
  ...
  |- 99_last_processed_file.sh
```

With `99_last_processed_file.sh` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
touch /tmp/server_can_shutdown.txt
```

--

In parallel, in Dockerfile, I run another script in replacement of Mortenn's "sleep && killall" :

```
# Dockerfile
# ...
COPY wait_then_shutdown.sh /tmp/wait_then_shutdown.sh
RUN /entrypoint.sh mysqld & /tmp/wait_then_shutdown.sh  # <-- 
RUN rm /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
```

With `wait_then_shutdown.sh` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [ ! -f /tmp/server_can_shutdown.txt ] # <-- created by 99_last_processed_file.sh
do
  sleep 2
done
kill $(pidof mysqld)
```

--

And now, `mysqld` stops only when all other files are processed in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Comment: I find that mysqld isn't handling the SIGTERM gracefully so when the container is run it complains about not being shutdown normally and runs a crash recovery.
I can avoid this by replacing `kill $(pidof mysqld)` with `mysqladmin shutdown` but if that is done straight away after the `server_can_shutdown` file is created, it interrupts `mysqld` as it starts up after the init process. So I'm back to adding another `sleep 30` like MegaWub's original script. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

Building on MegaWubs's answer, I found this Dockerfile to be sufficient.

```
FROM mysql:5.6
RUN sed -i 's|/var/lib/mysql|/var/lib/mysql2|g' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: Using mysql:5.7, I used:
```RUN sed -i 's|/var/lib/mysql|/var/lib/mysql2|g' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf```

Comment: I think they may have updated the location in mysql:5.6 as well.  I am using mysql:5.6 and had to use the path that Chomeh recommended.

Comment: `RUN sed -i 's|/var/lib/mysql|/var/lib/mysql2|g' /etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 3):

Starting Docker 17.05 it is possible to use multistage builds feature to remove volumes

```
# Dockerfile
FROM mysql as orig

FROM ubuntu:bionic as image
# care must be taken, this will not preserve fs ownership
COPY --from=orig / / # this will copy all files, without metadata.

ENV ... # include all commands that are not file related

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

and then add your data as in Phil Sabaty's answer.